# Best strategy to copy large distant folder with many files, faster than simple brute scp

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, scp

I have just finished a copy with basic scp of a large folder (80Gb dataset of small pictures) from Google Cloud with scp (Google Cloud scp, but it uses scp) in 15h, that's a lot of time.

I am looking for the best way to handle that case. I read that rsync could be faster, I am not sure if it change something when you don't have part of the folder on your computer.

I also read that [changing the cypher option could improve the speed](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/speeding-up-scp-872393/) but it is debatable.

I think also that maybe sending one big file would be faster than sending a lot of small ones. Thus sending an archive would be faster. Also an archive is compressed, thus lighter and faster to send, but the decompression can also take a lot of time. Compression is only a one time problem so I don't consider it.

So what is the best strategy to copy large large distant folder ?

Thank you.

**Edit:** In response to the comment, no encryption is needed and my internet connection is optical fiber, I don't know exactly the speed but it is fast.

The folder mainly contains triplets of pictures in pdf (~500kb) and png (one 1,5kb and another ~100kb), it also contains some tensorflow models and predictions that I don't necessarly needed, but it is not the big part and I will separate it from the pictures in the future. It's the work of a person who left and I just got it back. I am also in the company temporarily and I will organize this to facilitate the work of the next person.

Comment: Do you require encryption?  What kind of data are you sending (format, average size, etc)?  What is your receiving internet speed?  (And yes, sending lots of smaller files will be slower than one huge file.)

Comment: I have edted the post to answer your question.

Comment: `scp` also supports compression, that may speed things up.  Either way, I'd do it `rsync` over `ssh` just in case your transfer stops mid-way you'll be able to resume and not re-copy things

Comment: There are [commercial](https://asperasoft.com/) [solutions](https://www.signiant.com/) which are much faster than TCP-based copying, if you're willing to spend money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sftp and scp are limited in speed partly due to the encryption. If that is not highly necessary, you can setup an ftp server.

However you are using Google cloud, so I think you want to use the `gsutil cp` command.

You can find more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)

Basically it works by assigning a url to everything accessible on the cloud as if it were local. So imagine you have a bucket called `example`, you would use the following command to copy it to your local folder called `target_folder`

`gsutil cp - r gs://example target_folder`

You could add -m after gsutil if you have multiple smaller files to upload in parallel!

If this is the first time you use the gcloud command, frist run: `gcloud init` so that it's authorised and select the correct project on which the bucket is located.

Comment: Even for copying to my laptop ?

Comment: Yes. In the case of Google cloud the ftp server is not necessary, you can just use gsutil. I updated my original answer to give an example of how that would work from your laptop. In the more general case like you asked in your question, to transfer large files from pc to pc, use ftp!

Answer (score 1):

Use RSYNC. As youare copying many small files, rsync will only copy those  that have changed, saving a huge amount if time. Rsync has lots if flexibility in determining how to detect/handle changed and deleted files. (Its also trivial yo enable compression, but that is of limited benefit as the source docs look to be fairly compressed).

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes, best strategy would be to pack (without any compression just store it - the decompression would be fast) via e.g. rar (add a `-rr` to add recovery part) - into files 4GB large.

Next thing you may want to start multiple transfers which, if you have fast enough line could speed up things considerably.

Last thing to consider is to get rid of the encryption, if you don't need it. Use simple `ftp`.